# How to filter an array of multiple objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I have an array of multiple objects that is mocked and want to filter based on t_name_food.

```js
this.lista_categoria_food = [
      {
        n_id: 1, 
        t_nome_categorie: 'Main Dishes',
        t_image: 'Service.jpg',
        list_food: [
          { n_id: 1, 
          t_name_food: 'dish 1 ',
          t_price_food: 20, 
          n_quantity: 0, 
          t_quantity: 'piece' },

          { n_id: 2, 
          t_name_food: 'dish 2',
          t_price_food: 20, 
          n_quantity: 0, 
          t_quantity: 'piece' },

        ]
      },
      {
        n_id: 2, 
        t_nome_categorie: 'Appetizers',
        t_image: 'restaurant.jpg',
        list_food: [
          { n_id: 1, 
          t_name_food: 'food 1',
          t_price_food: 20,
          n_quantity: 0,
          t_quantity: 'piece' },
           { n_id: 2, 
           t_name_food: 'food 2',
           t_price_food: 20, 
           n_quantity: 0, 
           t_quantity: 'piece' },

        ]
      },
      ]
```

The filter should retrun the list of products that match in t_name_food.

Until now have tried to filter items of object.

```js
this.lista_categoria_food = this.filterFeeds.forEach((item) => {
      item.list_food.filter(e => 
   { 
  if(e.t_name_food.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
  return e;
} }) },
  );
```

Comment: Could you please share what have you tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: Please share your code attempt ? to achieve this! Thanks

Comment: Ok. Just edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Extended:**Now with letting the complete structure of the list and only showing the filtered items.

Iterate with forEach over your array *lista_categoria_food* and filter than for t_name_food on the array from property list_food from every object.
If there is at least 1 hit build a new res-object add these hits and complete the object with the other key/value-pairs from the origin-object. Collect all theses objects and return them.

```js
 function foodFilter(list, food) {
     let result = [];
     list.forEach(elem => {
         let list_food = elem.list_food.filter(obj => obj.t_name_food==food);
         if (list_food.length) {
             let res = {list_food: list_food};
             Object.keys(elem).map( key => {
                 if (key != "list_food") res[key] = elem[key];
             });
             result.push(res);
         }
     });
     return result;
 }

lista_categoria_food = [
      {
        n_id: 1, 
        t_nome_categorie: 'Main Dishes',
        t_image: 'Service.jpg',
        list_food: [
          { n_id: 1, 
          t_name_food: 'dish 1',
          t_price_food: 20, 
          n_quantity: 0, 
          t_quantity: 'piece' },

          { n_id: 2, 
          t_name_food: 'dish 2',
          t_price_food: 20, 
          n_quantity: 0, 
          t_quantity: 'piece' },

        ]
      },
      {
        n_id: 2, 
        t_nome_categorie: 'Appetizers',
        t_image: 'restaurant.jpg',
        list_food: [
          { n_id: 1, 
          t_name_food: 'food 1',
          t_price_food: 20,
          n_quantity: 0,
          t_quantity: 'piece' },
           { n_id: 2, 
           t_name_food: 'food 2',
           t_price_food: 20, 
           n_quantity: 0, 
           t_quantity: 'piece' },

        ]
      },
      ];
      
console.log(foodFilter(lista_categoria_food, 'food 2'));
console.log(foodFilter(lista_categoria_food, 'dish 1'));
```

Comment: i want to return lista_categoria_food array as structure but containing only filtered objects

Comment: @Stefani Totokotsopoulou I extended it to your wishes.

Comment: Do you want to have elements in your list which haven't after filtering any elements in list_food or not? At the moment I cut this elements out.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED filtered by an included string in t_name_food =>

```
let filtered = [];

this.lista_categoria_food.forEach(val => {
    val.list_food = val.list_food.filter(innerVal => {
         return innerVal.t_name_food.includes('dish 1')
       });
    if(val.list_food.length > 0) filtered.push(val);
});
```

now filtered holds the new array holding only the necessary t_name_food.

Filter by a specific string =>

You can filter by  t_name_food like this:

```
let filtered = this.lista_categoria_food.filter(val => {
    return val.list_food.filter(innerVal => {
        return innerVal.t_name_food === ('dish 1 ')}
    ).length > 0
});
```

the outer filter is filtered by the length of the inner filter list length.
I double filter the dishes.

in the example above I have filtered it by 'dish 1 '.

Comment: This is giving an empty array unless the word is exactly dish 1.

Comment: I just checked and the example gave an array filtered by 'dish 1 ', what have you tried? what you filter by?

Comment: sorry found a missing "}"
fixed it - try now :)

Comment: just notice that the example is by the data you uploaded and have space after dish 1 => 'dish 1 '

Comment: still it will give an result only if its full name. i want to filter with characters too.

Comment: instead of using comparison use includes, or you need regex?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219485/discussion-between-jon-m-and-stefani-totokotsopoulou).

Answer (score 0):

you can use .filter method to filter out the data that you want.
Please try the following approach to get your required data.

```
let temp = this.lista_categoria_food.filter((data)=>{
 let temp1=[];
data.list_food.forEach((food)=>{
  if(food.t_name_food==this.myMatch)
  {temp1.push(food)}
   } 
  return temp1
  })
```

Comment: i have tried this and gives and empty array with length 0.

Comment: Thank you. In this case the structure of temp and lista_categoria_food it will be different and this will not update my interface.

Comment: @MinalShah The filter method callback requires the return of a boolean value, you are always returning an array which will always evaluate to true.

Comment: If you want to keep the same array, you can just replace temp with your own array. This would achieve your goal.

Comment: @MinalShah the array lista_categoria_food it has a specific structure and cant be pushed directly the food.  
temp1.push(food)

Comment: What is your exact requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) in order to filter:

```js
const lista_categoria_food = [
      {
        n_id: 1, 
        t_nome_categorie: 'Main Dishes',
        t_image: 'Service.jpg',
        list_food: [
          { n_id: 1, 
          t_name_food: 'dish 1 ',
          t_price_food: 20, 
          n_quantity: 0, 
          t_quantity: 'piece' },

          { n_id: 2, 
          t_name_food: 'dish 2',
          t_price_food: 20, 
          n_quantity: 0, 
          t_quantity: 'piece' },

        ]
      },
      {
        n_id: 2, 
        t_nome_categorie: 'Appetizers',
        t_image: 'restaurant.jpg',
        list_food: [
          { n_id: 1, 
          t_name_food: 'food 1',
          t_price_food: 20,
          n_quantity: 0,
          t_quantity: 'piece' },
           { n_id: 2, 
           t_name_food: 'food 2',
           t_price_food: 20, 
           n_quantity: 0, 
           t_quantity: 'piece' },

        ]
      },
      ];
      
      
    const filtered = lista_categoria_food.filter(({list_food}) => list_food.some(({t_name_food}) => t_name_food === 'food 1'));
    
    console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: i want to return lista_categoria_food array as structure but containing only filtered objects

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

This snippet allows you to enter a search string in an input field. The resulting object is printed in the console via console.log.

[[ The "cloning" step is crucial in my script! If you left it out the function will seem to work at first, but after the first filter operation the source object will be changed permanently. ]]

```js
const pre=document.querySelector('pre');
document.querySelector('input').oninput=ev=>{
  const res=food.map(f=>{
    let ff={...f}; // clone each f object for later filtering
    ff.list_food=ff.list_food.filter(lf=> // filter list_food
      lf.t_name_food.match(new RegExp(ev.target.value,'i')));
    return ff;})
  console.log(res); // or do with it, whatever you like ...
}

const food = [
      {
        n_id: 1, 
        t_nome_categorie: 'Main Dishes',
        t_image: 'Service.jpg',
        list_food: [
          { n_id: 1, 
          t_name_food: 'dish 1 ',
          t_price_food: 20, 
          n_quantity: 0, 
          t_quantity: 'piece' },

          { n_id: 2, 
          t_name_food: 'dish 2',
          t_price_food: 20, 
          n_quantity: 0, 
          t_quantity: 'piece' },

        ]
      },
      {
        n_id: 2, 
        t_nome_categorie: 'Appetizers',
        t_image: 'restaurant.jpg',
        list_food: [
          { n_id: 1, 
          t_name_food: 'food 1',
          t_price_food: 20,
          n_quantity: 0,
          t_quantity: 'piece' },
           { n_id: 2, 
           t_name_food: 'food 2',
           t_price_food: 20, 
           n_quantity: 0, 
           t_quantity: 'piece' },

        ]
      },
      ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:90% !important}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: i want to return food array as structure but containing only filtered objects

Comment: The new version of my script will return an array of exactly the same structure as the input, but the contained `list_food`-arrays are filtered and will contain only items that match the given filter string.